# How to send BufferedReader and PrintWriter through intents

Tags: android, android-intent, chat

I'm creating an android chat application and i cannot figure out how to pass my bufferedReader and Printwriter to my other classes. i attempted to create a global class extending the application class but i had no such luck.

I'm sure how to implement  parcable or serializable and then put the writer and reader in there so i can pass it through intents

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm creating an android chat application and i cannot figure out how to pass my bufferedReader and Printwriter to my other classes.

You don't, at least not via `Intent` extras.

> All suggestions are welcome!

Since you declined to state what the "bufferedReader and Printwriter" are for — so that we could reliably help you — we are forced to make a random guess. I am going to guess that you are using these with the socket connection to the chat server.

In that case, there really should only be one Android component that needs them: your service that is managing your thread for your socket.

When a chat message comes in, and you wish to display it, have your service let your UI layer know about the message: `LocalBroadcastManager`, [Square's Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), etc.

When you wish to send a chat message, call `startService()` to send the command to the service.

Comment: My question is, is that i have a intentservice that handles all incoming messages in while(in.readLine()) so how would that service also handle sending messages? Also, what if i were to extend all my classes to the class that contains the socket connection?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the singleton pattern. For instance, you could create a class with a static member that holds the stream or collection of streams. Perhaps you use a map to associate a string with the particular stream. Then send the other activities the key via an intent which they then use to access the associated stream.